# MySQL Join 3 Tables and Count Table 3 by ID from Table 1 and Table 2

Tags: mysql, count, sum, inner-join

I have three table, and want to sum the total result from table B, because table B will get total result with `count(*)` from table C. I've already know how to get `count(*)` total with 2 tables, but i didn't have any idea how to combine 3 table. Here's the example and result what i want.

It's like Table A have a Child in Table B and SOME of Table B have a child in Table C, so i just want to know how many a whole of Table A grandchild

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

And here's the code i've already try using combine with just 2 tables:

```
SELECT 
    table_a.*, 
    (
        SELECT 
            count(*) 
        FROM 
            table_b 
        WHERE 
            table_b.id_b = table_a.id_A
    ) AS totala 
FROM 
    table_a
```

Comment: Can you please explain the result ?

Comment: @Mureinik thanks for your respond, i've already include result example. Like the example above, Music will have 4 total data because data from Table C - id_B is equal with Table B - id_B and Table B - id_A is equal of Table A - id_A

Comment: @JhonnyJr. going by that logic, shouldn't the count for `Movie` be 5?

Comment: @DarshanMehta Movie is 3 because Data from Table C which have relation with Table B is just 3 data

Comment: @JhonnyJr. Yes, but data from table b in relation with table A is 4 rows. So, should it be 4 + 1 = 5?

Comment: @DarshanMehta it's like Table A have a Child in Table B and some of Table B have a child in Table C, so i just want to know how many of Table A grandchild

Comment: @JhonnyJr. I have added an answer, let me know if that's fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try the following:

```
SELECT a.id_A, a.Name, COUNT(c.id_c) AS total
FROM table_a a
LEFT JOIN table_B b ON a.id_A = b.id_A
LEFT JOIN table_C c ON b.id_B = c.id_B
GROUP BY a.id_a;
```

Here's the **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ccec7/4/0)**.

Comment: It give me result of "syntax error near *)" :( but if i remove of "c" from COUNT(), it just display with an empty result

Comment: @JhonnyJr. Amended the query and added the SQL Fiddle. Let me know if that's fine now..

Comment: Oh damn, it's work :O you're so great, thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Could be you need  th count for the joined  table

```
select a.id_A, a.name, count(*) 
from tableA a
left join tableB b on a.id_A  = b.id_A
left join tableC c on c.id_b = b.id_b
group by a.id_A, a.name
```

Comment: It just give me result of total from table b which is have relation with table a, not with table c :(

Answer (score 0):

I think your are looking for this:

```
SELECT A.*, COUNT(*) as Total
FROM table A
INNER JOIN table B using(id_A)
INNER JOIN table C using(id_B)
GROUP BY A.id_A ;
```

Comment: It give me result Unknown Column 'ID_A' from clause

Comment: There was an upper case in a column_name in my answer. but that shouldn't matter. I guess it's fine, as you already got your answer.